# Group posts by date with a list

Tags: loop, date

I want to set a group of posts grouped by date as a list. Below is what I would like to have:

```
Day...
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
Previous day...
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

I did that:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_date(); ?>
<li><a href="#"><?php the_time(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I don't really know where to put the
    < ul >
or
    < /ul >
tags. Any idea?

Actually, setting the starting tag is OK by doing this:

```
<?php the_date('','','<ul>'); ?>
```

But I can't figure out how to set the closing tag.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually perform a simple check to see if that day has changed.

```
<?php 
$day_check = '';
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  $day = get_the_date('j');
  if ($day != $day_check) {
    if ($day_check != '') {
      echo '</ul>'; // close the list here
    }
    echo get_the_date() . '<ul>';
  }
?>
<li><a href="#"><?php the_time(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php 
$day_check = $day;
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake :/ It gives me something like this:
<ul><li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul><li><a href="#">...</a></li>

The closing UL is wrongly placed :( (and the date is no more displayed).

Comment: sorry, it was adapted from another file that does something slightly different. I edited the code above.

Comment: Thank you. I just had to add </ul> outside the loop to close the last list. Thx :)